# How to remove spaces for my reverse concatenate macro?

Tags: excel, vba

My code works however, it's showing spaces. What happens here is is when I put values in A1 cell like Tom,John,Mark,Bob. From concatenated list, it will be in reverse concatenate. It should show like below:

```
Tom
John
Mark
Bob
```

But for now, it shows with spaces like below:

```
Tom
 John
 Mark
 Bob
```

How do I get ride with the spaces?

```
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+l
'
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Selection.Copy
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: `Selection.Resize(Ubound(Split(Selection,","))+1).Value = Application.Transpose(Split(Replace(Selection," ",""),","))`

Comment: @ScottCraner where should I place this?

Comment: replace everything in the sub with that one line.  Select the cell you want to split and hit `Ctrl-l`

Comment: This is what happens in my macro. 1st - Whatever is in A1 cell will be separated to each cell to the right, and the reverse concatenate should start in A3.

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Resize(Ubound(Split(ActiveSheet.Range("A1"),","))+1).Value = Application.Transpose(Split(Replace(ActiveSheet.Range("A1")," ",""),","))`

Comment: @ScottCraner Totally what I wanted! Thank you Scott!

Comment: @Jezun: Are you sure that your string in A1 was "Tom,John,Mark,Bob" as you say, or "Tom, John, Mark, Bob"?